# Losing anti-aliasing of UIImage after reloading the UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I have this code:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"route-manually-add@3x.png"];

UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8,7, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height)] autorelease];

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, true);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, true);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);

[imageView.layer setMinificationFilter:kCAFilterTrilinear];
[imageView.layer setAllowsEdgeAntialiasing:YES];
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.bounds.size.width, imageView.bounds.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
[myImage drawInRect : CGRectMake (0,0, imageView.bounds.size.width, imageView.bounds.size.height)];
myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[imageView setImage:myImage];
imageView.layer.shouldRasterize=YES;
imageView.layer.edgeAntialiasingMask = kCALayerLeftEdge | kCALayerRightEdge | kCALayerBottomEdge | kCALayerTopEdge;
imageView.clipsToBounds=NO;
imageView.layer.masksToBounds=NO;
[mycell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

Which i am using to remove the distortion happening to the image, and it works for the first time but when i reload my `TableView` then it loses its anti-aliasing.

FYI:This image is added into the cell which is of type UITableViewCell.
Please help me out with this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of image?

Comment: I have attached the images, please check it, the first one is looking better but after table is reloaded it looses its anti-aliasing